# Angular : Parent subscribe for changes in child component via service not working

Tags: angular, routes, parent-child

I have implement service method before but seems like its not working now. I have a structure of my folder like this.

```
------createCompany
                      ------- Login  [login.component.ts,login.component.html]
                      ------- profile  [profile.component.ts,profile.component.html]
                      ------- common  [common.component.ts,common.component.html]
```

My `commonComponent` is basically my parent component and its `html` look something like this.

```
    <div class="company-container">

          <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    </div>
```

Here is my`createCompany.routing.ts` file.

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CompanyCommonComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'create-company/:1',
        component: CompanyLoginComponent,
        resolve: {
          resolvedData: RouteResolverService
        },
        data: { apiUrl: Globals.urls.serviceProviders.codes, methodType: 'GET', paramsAvailable: false }
      },
      {
        path: 'create-company/:2',
        component: CompanyProfileComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'create-company/:3',
        component: CompanyDetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'create-company/:4',
        component: CompanyPreviewComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'create-company/1',
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Now i Have made a service called `createCompany.service.ts` and it look like this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CreateCompanyService {

  constructor() { }

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject(1);
  data$ = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  stepChanged(step: number) {
    this.messageSource.next(step)
  }

}
```

Now I am subscribing for change in my parent component which is `common.component.ts` like this. But unfortunately it just displays for the first time the default value.

**commonComponent.ts (parent)**

```
  export class CompanyCommonComponent implements OnInit {

  step: number;

  constructor(private data: CreateCompanyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.data$.subscribe(step => this.step = step)
    console.log(this.step)
  }
}
```

and this is my child component which is calling the service function, but parent is unable to detect it.

**companyLogin.component.ts**

```
    export class CompanyLoginComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private data : CreateCompanyService) { }
    next(stepType) {
      this.data.stepChanged(2)
    }
   }
```

please tell me what I am doing wrong ? I have been stuck in this for 4 hrs.

Comment: How do you know your parent component can't detect the change? Your `console.log` in the parent component is outside of the subscribe, so it will only ever log the initial value.

Comment: i tried it in the subscribe too still no result

Comment: Here's a messy copy-paste recreation in stackblitz that works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcmeaf perhaps there's something else you haven't shown us that is causing an issue?